# Overrides only for certain derived classes

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, c++23

Is there a way to make only certain derived classes of a class, call it `Base`, override a virtual method, call it `foo()`, of `Base`?  The reason I need this is because all the derived classes of `Base` that I want to have overrides of `Base::foo()` I've declared final, and any derived classes of `Base` henceforth shall derive only from these and call invoke their (final) overrides of `foo()`.  But because `Base::foo()` is not (and cannot) be declared final, I may accidentally create a new derived class of `Base` and thus define a catastrophic override of `Base::foo()`.  So how do I prevent this from happening, and force a compiling error if I ever do, apart from making sure that I remember not to?

Comment: Make the Base constructors private and declare the known set of allowed derived classes friends. No other class can now derive from Base because a derived class will always, implicitly or explicitly, invoke the base class constructor.

Comment: With this little information it is unclear WHAT you are trying to model, you only describe a "problem" with the design you've chosen (and it often happens to me that if things become "difficult" it is a sign I need to take a different design approach. Maybe you something like (CRTP) mixin of implementations.  Maybe you don't need (runtime) polymorphism at all. So can you try to explain WHAT you are trying to achieve? Or at least add a minimum reprodicible code example to your question?

Comment: You description is very confusing. Instead of describing your code, please *show it* to us, in the form of a [mre].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think that the OP tries to describe the problem I posted a solution for.

Comment: Reinstate Monica might have a more general working solution for me, so I will produce a code example later if a more specific solution is needed.

Comment: How can you "accidentally" create a derived class?